# C incosistent result with negative index of array

Tags: c, arrays

I have two arrays and out of both I have to get the Values of specific Indices. While doing this I have comme accross something odd. When I print out the value at index -1 of arr1, I get 0 and the same thing happens with index 8. I concluded that inidces outside the range of an array are returned as 0. Now my problem. When I do the same thing with arr2, I get 29 as the Value of index -1. 
What am I doing wrong?

```
int arr1[] = {33, 12, 75, 85, 62, 14, 100, 29};

printf("Nummer -1: %d\n",arr1[-1]); //outputs 0
printf("Nummer 8: %d\n",arr1[8]; //outputs 0


int arr2[] = {85, 15, 84, 96, 4, 45, 55, 12, 25, 68};
printf("Nummer -1: %d\n",arr2[-1]); //outputs 29
```

Note: I use Code:Blocks on Linux Mint with the gcc compiler

Comment: as long as it points to the valid address you can use negative index..otherwise it is UB

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ its -1, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I concluded that indices outside the range of an array are returned as 0.

That's a wrong conclusion to draw: accessing indices outside the range of an array produces undefined behavior. The access may also produce arbitrary values, but it could also crash your program: once undefined behavior is invoked, the program is in an invalid state.

> When I do the same thing with `arr2`, I get 29 as the Value of index -1.

In this particular case your program appears to read a value from a different array (i.e. the last value in `arr1`). This is still undefined behavior, though, so doing this results in an invalid program.

Answer (score 1):

Negative array index illegal in C and C++. it is invoked [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in C.

**From C11 §6.5.2.1 Array subscripting**

> A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets `[]`
>   is a subscripted designation of an element of an array object. **The
>   definition of the subscript operator `[]` is that `E1[E2]` is
>   identical to `(*((E1)+(E2)))`.** Because of the conversion rules that
>   apply to the binary + operator, if `E1` is an array object
>   (equivalently, a pointer to the initial element of an array object)
>   and E2 is an integer, `E1[E2]` designates the E2-th element of `E1`
>   (counting from zero).

[Clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/pYkN9cvWD0cjKDnI) compiler generated warning

```
warning: array index -1 is before the beginning of the array [-Warray-bounds]
printf("Nummer -1: %d\n",arr1[-1]); //outputs 0
```